# process pdf attachments with applescript and pdfpenpro

Tags: email, applescript

I've set up a gmail account that will contain nothing but emails with pdf attachments. I've also set apple mail up to check this account. Now, I would like to set up an applescript to take the pdfs from this account, put them in a folder, and OCR them with pdfpenpro. Is there a way to do this?